# NSException when displaying UIAlertController in own window

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, uiwindow, nsexception

I am trying to show a UIAlertController over a UISplitViewController. I have tried everything that I have found on this site, and am sticking with an extension found here.

extension UIAlertController {

```
func presentInOwnWindow(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
        alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)
}
```

I get an exception immediately after present executes, and I can't see the stack trace and the exception breakpoint is not fired.

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

It presents fine on a phone with the UISplitViewController collapsed. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you calling this function on the main thread? Perhaps you should surround this code with DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }

Comment: Also you are setting rootViewController to a newly created UIViewController(). Shouldn't you be setting this to the current view controller

Comment: It is on the main thread. I actually removed a dispatch to main to post this because it was on the main thread anyway. The rootViewController is created and added as a root to the new window that overlays the currentViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Potential problem is `UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;`. Try to use `UIWindowLevelNormal` instead. The new window will be placed above your default window. And above `UISplitViewController` too.

```
func presentInOwnWindow(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)
}
```

Comment: Still crashes. I have also tried removing windowLevel entirely.

Comment: This works for me. Please review https://github.com/AlexeyGolovenkov/TestWindow. Try to add All Exceptions breakpoint (Breakpoint navigator -> + -> Exception breakpoint) and check the result.

Comment: I keep getting a crash. I am on 11.1. Also, you project has the master collapsed. It crashes with the master open, at least for me.

Comment: It's strange. I don't see crash with any state of master controller. BTW I see alert even without custom window. Are you sure the problem is in alert?